# Techniques for generating sequential numbers for table

Tags: java, db2

We are currently using a database table to manage the generation of sequential numbers to be used for many table.  Because this table is used by numerous other routines, we get a deadlock situation from time to time.

We would be interested to hear what other techniques can be use to generate sequential numbers for tables.  Each table will run a different sequential series for different company data within the table.

Answer (score 3):

There are special objects suitable for the automatic generation of values called [Sequences](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0023175.html):

> A *sequence* is a database object that allows the automatic generation
>   of values, such as cheque numbers. Sequences are ideally suited to the
>   task of generating unique key values. Applications can use sequences
>   to avoid possible concurrency and performance problems resulting from
>   column values used to track numbers. The advantage that sequences have
>   over numbers created outside the database is that the database server
>   keeps track of the numbers generated. A crash and restart will not
>   cause duplicate numbers from being generated.

Comment: Lots of useful features are built into `sequence` objects: Automatic rollover, step and range size and forced ordering VS caching.